# Java how to get abbreviation according from offset

Tags: java

I have Offset value Like UTC+3 I want  abbreviation of it in java

Comment: Java != Javascript

Comment: I know..its java or js

Comment: Questions asking for *homework help* **must** include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it ([help], [ask]).

Comment: Use `ZoneOffset` ([official Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/timezones.html)). Also you might want to do some research before ([Google query: java time offset to timezone](https://www.google.de/search?q=java+time+offset+to+timezone)) which immediately yields those sites and also some similar SO questions. Also see [Wikipedia: TimeZone database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database).

Comment: You can't; you can only guess. For example, UTC+1 is that British Summer Time (BST), or Central European Time (CET)?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Good point, but maybe a set of all matching time zone names is then what OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

An adaptation of [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/timezones.html) might be of use.

```
Set<String> allZones = ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds();
        LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.now();

        List<String> zoneList = new ArrayList<>(allZones);
        Collections.sort(zoneList);

        zoneList.stream().map((s) -> ZoneId.of(s)).forEach((zone) -> {
            ZonedDateTime zdt = dt.atZone(zone);
            ZoneOffset offset = zdt.getOffset();
            String out = String.format("%35s %10s%n", zone, offset);
            if (offset.getTotalSeconds() == 10800) {
                System.out.printf(out);
            }
        });
```